# accessing value of key defined in properties file

Tags: spring

**I am working with maven based spring mvc project.**
    I have configured `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean as follows with the following locations property value:

**my root-context.xml:**

```
<!-- beans config-->
    <bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">     
            <property name="locations">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath:kiran.properties</value>               
                </list>
            </property>
    </bean>
```

**and my kiran.properties:**

```
    #properties file
    excel.dirpath=root/Desktop/exceluploads/kiran/
```

**and in my CMISUploadImpl.java:**

```
    public @Value("${excel.dirpath}")
    String alfrescoSpaceStore;

    //accessing key defined in properties file
    Sytem.out.prinln(alfrescoSpaceStore);

    o/p:${excel.dirpath}
```

I am getting the above o/p when accessing key value in my above said java file. I am unable to access the value of key that is defined in above said properties file. I am not getting what is wrong with my above code.

Comment: Can you show some more from your applicationContext.xml? + Where is your kiran.properties file? Are you sure it is in your classpath?

Comment: Hi Shlomi33, thanks for your kind reply.properties file is in  src/main/resources folder.

Comment: and moreover i am getting following server console message while deploying my spring mvc project in server:      INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [kiran.properties]

Comment: Is the CMISUploadImpl a managed Bean?